# Error: Handshake inactivity timeout when trying to access RDS from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, amazon-aurora

I have a lambda function using the serverless framework. I created a security group and associated it with the lambda function, I also included all 3 subnetIDs that the RDS uses in the serverless.yml. I then associated the new lambda security group with the security group that the RDS is saying it's using. I have it set for MySQL\Aurora on the inbound tab and the source being the new lambda sg.

When I run the lambda I get the handshake inactivity timeout when trying to connect my pool to the instance. I use this same security group to give myself access to the database via IP, so I know it has to be the right instance. What am I missing?

Here is the definition for the function in serverless.yml

```
consumer:
    handler: consumer/handler.testconsumer
    timeout: 29
    memorySize: 512
    vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
        - sg-lambda
      subnetIds:
        - subnet-1
        - subnet-2
        - subnet-3
```

I also have the following IAM role statement to allow the networking. Though serverless does bark at this:

Warned - iamRoleStatement granting Resource='*'. Wildcard resources in iamRoleStatements are not permitted.

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action: 
        - "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
        - "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces"
        - "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
      Resource: "*"
```

Is that causing an issue? I'm beating my head against a wall about this.